# Razorpay web API verification step

Tags: node.js, reactjs, razorpay

In the Razorpay web API docs, it is given that on successful payment, three things are returned to the Checkout form, i.e `razorpay_order_id, razorpay_payment_id` and `razorpay_signature`. For verification, we need to generate a signature from `order_id`(this we get from order creation) `, razorpay_payment_id` and `key_secret` which we get from the dashboard. If the generated signature and `razorpay_signature` match then the payment is verified. My question what are we verifying here (What would happen if skipped this step?, i.e the purpose of this step) and also I think if the payment was successful then the `razorpay_order_id` which we got would be the same as `order_id`. Why don't we just compare the order_id and `razorpay_order_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mandatory step that allows you to confirm the authenticity of the details returned to the Checkout form for successful payments.

The idea is not to just compare the orderIds as, the orderId is a part of the UI and is visible with the view source.

Say, we are expecting only orderId and paymentId.

A hacker generates a random payment id, and triggers a payment success call back with orderId(visible in source) and paymentId . How do we identify here that the paymentId is a valid one ?

If the signature you generate on your server matches the razorpay_signature returned to you by the Checkout form, the payment received is from an authentic source.

When we verify the signature we are able to indetify that this is a valid callback from Razorpay servers